# How to set x and y axis columns in python subplot matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

```
def plot(self):
    plt.figure(figsize=(20, 5))

    ax1 = plt.subplot(211)
    ax1.plot(self.signals['CLOSE'])
    ax1.set_title('Price')

    ax2 = plt.subplot(212, sharex=ax1)
    ax2.set_title('RSI')
    ax2.plot(self.signals[['RSI']])
    ax2.axhline(30, linestyle='--', alpha=0.5, color='#ff0000')
    ax2.axhline(70, linestyle='--', alpha=0.5, color='#ff0000')
    
    plt.show()
```

I am plotting two charts in python application. But the x axis values are indexes like 1,2,3,....

But my dataframe has a column `self.signals['DATA']` so how can I use it as x axis values?

Answer (score 0):

With `set_xticks` you set, where the positions are, for example:

```
ax1.set_xticks([1, 2, 3])
```

and with `set_xticklabels` you can define what it says there:

```
ax1.set_xticklabels(['one', 'two', 'three'])
```

see https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_xticklabels.html for more options.

Answer (score 0):

> But the x axis values are indexes like 1,2,3,...
>
> But my dataframe has a column self.signals['DATA'] so how can I use it as x axis values?

I assume you are using pandas and matplotlib.

According to [matplotlib documentation](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.plot.html), you can simply pass the X and Y values to the plot function.

So instead of calling

```
ax1.plot(self.signals['CLOSE'])
```

you can for instance do:

```
ax1.plot(self.signals['DATA'], self.signals['CLOSE'])
```

Depending on other arguments, this will do a scatter plot or a line plot.
see matplotlib documentation for more fine tuning of your charts.

or you could even try:

```
plot('DATA', 'CLOSE', data=self.signals)
```

---

Quoting documentation:

> Call signatures:
>
> `plot([x], y, [fmt], *, data=None, **kwargs)`
>
> `plot([x], y, [fmt], [x2], y2, [fmt2], ..., **kwargs)`